# How to write joins Rails ActiveRecord_Relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
> u = User.first
> u.viewable_cars
OR
> Car.for(u)
```

would get me just the cars the user has permission to view but not the cars he owns! SQL in irb for both u.viewable_cars & Car.for(u), which is the same, cars with id 1 to 50 which belongs to user don't get called at all:

```
SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" INNER JOIN "permissions" ON "permissions"."thing_id" = "cars"."id"     AND "permissions"."thing_type" = $1 WHERE ((cars.user_id = 1) OR (permissions.action = 'view' AND permissions.user_id = 1))  ORDER BY created_at DESC  [["thing_type", "Car"]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Car id: 52, content: "sport edition", name: "BMW", user_id: 2, created_at: "2014-11-01 04:58:19", updated_at: "2014-11-01 04:58:19">, #<Car id: 51, content: "super sport car", name: "BMW M6", user_id: 3, created_at: "2014-11-01 04:44:31", updated_at: "2014-11-01 04:44:31">]>

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :permissions, as: :thing

   default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
   validates :user_id, presence: true
   validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }, uniqueness: true
   validates :content, length: { maximum: 300 }, allow_blank: true

   scope :viewable_by, ->(user) do
      joins(:permissions).where(permissions: { action: "view",
                                         user_id: user.id })
   end

  scope :for, ->(user) do
     joins(:permissions).
     where("(cars.user_id = :user_id) OR (permissions.action = 'view' AND permissions.user_id = :user_id)", user_id: user.id)
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   has_many :cars, dependent: :destroy

   has_many :permissions

   has_many :viewable_cars, ->(user) { joins(:permissions).
       where("(cars.user_id = :user_id) OR (permissions.action = 'view' AND permissions.user_id   = :user_id)", user_id: user.id) },
       class_name: "Car"

   def viewable_cars
      Car.for(self)
   end
 end


 class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :thing, polymorphic: true
 end

 Rails.application.routes.draw do
   resources :users do
     resources :cars
   end
end
```

Comment: Are you using `cancan`?

Comment: Try: `u = User.first; u.cars.merge(Car.viewable_by(u))`

Comment: it doesn't work. When I use Car.viewable_by(current_user).find_by(id: params[:id]) in Cars controller i can view the cars the current_user has permission but I cannot access current_user cars. In order to see current_user cars i have to switch to current_user.cars.find_by(id: params[:id]). I need to find a way so i can view both current_user cars and the ones he has permission to view..

Comment: it doesn't work: `current_user.cars.merge(Car.viewable_by(current_user)).find_by(params[:id])`? You mean you don't see the car or it gives error?

Comment: so in the private part of the cars controller u set the right instance variable car = current_user.cars.find_by(id: params[:id]) which in turn is used in the show action. if i use car = current_user.cars.merge(Car.viewable_by(current_user)).find_by(params[:id]) it is nil car.nil?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned it correctly. Don't use `find_by` use `find(params[:id])`. Also, can you post what query: `current_user.cars.merge(Car.viewable_by(current_user)).find(params[:id])` is generating? This is actually similar(but uses ActiveRelation instead) to your `scope :for, ->(user) do` you mentioned in your question. However, you can try: `Car.where("user_id = ?", user).joins(:permissions).where(permissions: { action: "view",
                                             user_id: user.id })` but that'd be again the same thing.

Comment: I tried in rails console. It just returns the cars the current_user has permissions to view spitting the following sql: SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" INNER JOIN "permissions" ON "permissions"."thing_id" = "cars"."id" AND "permissions"."thing_type" = 'Car' WHERE "cars"."user_id" = ? AND "permissions"."action" = 'view' AND "permissions"."user_id" = 1  ORDER BY created_at DESC  [["user_id", 1]]. So it doesn't even execute the current_user.cars at all..

Comment: Actually, it does execute `current_user.cars`. It make sense why you're not getting the desired data because you have an `AND` instead of `OR`. Try this: `Car.joins(:permissions).where("(user_id = :user_id) OR (permissions.action = 'view' AND permissions.user_id = :user_id)", user_id: current_user.id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scope `for` in *car.rb* should be this:

```
scope :for, ->(user) do
  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN permissions ON permissions.thing_id = cars.id AND permissions.thing_type = 'Car'").where("(cars.user_id = :user_id) OR (permissions.action = 'view' AND permissions.user_id = :user_id)", user_id: user.id)
end
```

Now you can do: `Car.for(current_user).find(params[:id])`. However, this looks like an antipattern to me. So you can create another association in *user.rb* like this:

**Rails 4**:

```
has_many :viewable_cars, ->(user) { 
         joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN permissions ON permissions.thing_id = cars.id AND permissions.thing_type = 'Car'").
         where("(cars.user_id = :user_id) OR (permissions.action = 'view' AND permissions.user_id = :user_id)", user_id: user.id) }, 
  class_name: 'Car'
```

**Rails 3**(couldn't find a better way of doing it, e.g.: associations):

```
def viewable_cars
  Car.for(self)
end
```

So that you can fetch all cars for user:

```
current_user.viewable_cars
```

In controller:

```
@car = current_user.viewable_cars.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: it doesn't work man. In both cases I tried in the terminal it gives an error: PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "user_id" is ambiguous.. and I'm using Rails 4.1.6 & 4.2.0beta.

Comment: See the update answer. That may have happened because of user_id being present in both cars and permissions tables

Comment: I did everything you said but i get same result just the cars the user has permission to view. See updated question. I really appreciate you help.

Comment: Forget everything, try this query: `Car.joins(:permissions).where("cars.user_id = :user_id AND permissions.action = 'view'", user_id: current_user.id).find(params[:id))` and update with what you get.

Comment: the following sql statement gets me all the id (just ids) of cars the current_user owns and has permission to view: SELECT thing_id FROM permissions WHERE user_id = 1 AND action = 'view' UNION ALL SELECT id FROM cars WHERE user_id = 1;

Comment: @eri : You know what? I am feeling bad that I can't figure out such a small issue, can you give this query a try?: `Car.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN permissions ON permissions. thing_id = cars.id AND "permissions"."thing_type" = 'Car'").where("(cars.user_id = :user_id) OR (permissions.action = 'view' AND permissions.user_id = :user_id)", user_id: current_user.id)` and about the query you've posted. If it works then you can call it with: `ActiveRecord::base.execute(sql)`.

Comment: thank you Jesus!! this works: Car.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN permissions ON permissions.thing_id = cars.id AND permissions.thing_type = 'Car'").where("(cars.user_id = :user_id) OR (permissions.action = 'view' AND permissions.user_id = :user_id)", user_id: current_user.id). Now how do I use it in my Cars controller to define an instance variable /@/car for current_user so i can pass it to the show action..?

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you so much @User089247 I really appreciate it. really saved my bacon :)

Comment: @eri : Oh, finally! See the updated answer. and don't forget to mark it as accepted by checking green tick mark on left side. :)